# Using VMMap in a batch script

Tags: windows, memory-management, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am doing some analysis work on some software we are running where I work. The software seems to have memory issues some where along the line which are proving difficult to track down. We have decided to use Sysinternals VMMap to track the memory being used by the software.

We have VMMap exporting the usage every 20 seconds using Windows scheduler to launch a batch script which pulls back the target process PID and launches VMMap with it. The process runs for a while, output appearing the out directory but after a while it stops. Windows scheduler reports the job ran fine and will start another instance when the trigger is meant, once again with no output.

After a bit of investigation it looks like VMMap is failing to open the process and is trying to report an error through its GUI. Since we are running in batch, we cannot see this error to dismiss it. This is causing numerous process' to be spawned but not actually doing anything.

Has anyone come across this issue when using VMMap, or know of anything that may help? I am thinking there may be some flag I can pass which suppresses messages or maybe some way I can handle it in the batch but Google hasn't helped nor has the Sysinternals forum. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) is a GUI tool, so trying to capture its output in an automated way will be difficult. Instead, try using another SysInternals tool, [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb896655), that captures a lot of the same information, but exports/reports on it in command line, where it can be captured much easier. Alternatively, don't run the output in an auto-repeating way when using VMMap, but instead have your script somehow detect the error or missing expected results/data and stop so the GUI output can be examined.

Comment: This is the method we ended up going for. We minimized the chance of passing in an invalid PID by rechecked before to call (Since it was in a for loop sometimes the PID closed before it was reached) and by killing off any VMMap processes running when we knew they shouldn't be running.

Answer (score 0):

All Sysinternals tools do pop up a consent dialog for the first time they are started on a new machine to accept their license. I think you did deploy the tool to a production machine and it was trying to show the consent dialog but nobody did press ok.

They do basically create a registry key on the machine which you can fake if you need a fully automated deployement or you can start in once on the target machine for the user in question.

Comment: We had made sure to accept the initial license dialog, the process initiated and created data for a while but stopped after some time